# Twilio Video - Connecting muted Programmable Voice calls?

Tags: twilio

I'm currently working on building an application using Twilio's Programmable Video. I've demonstrated the voice dial-in (Connect -> Room) for users want to dial in without a web browser. We've got a requirement for "listening in" - this is achievable with those users running through a browser (ie: don't send audio/video streams) but we've been unable to find a way to connect a Programmable Voice user through without including their audio. Any ideas?

Possible thoughts I've had, but been unable to build a solution for:

- incoming call, stream the audio from the Programmable Video instead?
- bridge onto a conference call, then mute the participants?
- outgoing call -> connect to room and call into a conference, again with muted participants?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure you can currently connect a voice call to a video room without sending an audio stream.

On the other hand, you have the power in the Video SDK and the client side to mute the audio from the voice call too by never playing the media stream from the listener to any of the other participants. If you don't attach the media stream to the DOM, then it will never play.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Hi Phil - sadly not - we'd be looking to have both "active" (ie: listen and talk) and "passive" (ie: listen only) phone participants - we'd be able to achieve either/or this way - but not both, given you couldn't prevent an "active" phone caller receiving "passive" users' audio.

Comment: Ahhh. The issue is that all users on the phone will be able to hear other phone users. I would probably approach this with a conference call, as you suggested. You can have a passive conference room that when someone dials into puts them in the conference muted and, if it's the first person to dial in, then generates an outbound call to the same conference number and when connected to that will dial into the room. You said you've not managed to achieve any of the solutions you suggested, what's going wrong there for you?

Comment: I think with this one it's been not knowing where to start. Just done some further investigation and it looks like it should be possible - a statusCallbackEvent on join, which then triggers a new outbound SIP call to the conference with "url" set to some TwiML to handle a connection into the conference itself. Should be doable from the look of it. Looks like some prototyping is in order... Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No worries, and good luck with it. That sounds like the right sort of path 