# Twilio SIP: Calling to TwiML application on SIP endpoint

Tags: twilio

Apologies if I've missed something obvious, but...

I'm currently trying to use the Twilio REST API to create a call between a conference call and a video room - ie:

- There exists a TwiML app to connect into a conference call (A)
- There exists a video room (B)
- There exists a SIP Domain (xxx.sip.twilio.com) with its Request URL set to a web service that produces TwiML to connect to the conference call A
- I am attempting to join the two with an outgoing SIP call that calls the SIP endpoint and joins the video room

To create the call, I'm using the following code extract to create the call:

```cs
var call = CallResource.Create(
    to: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber($"sip:xxx.sip.ie1.twilio.com?X-FriendlyName={FriendlyName}"),
    from: new Twilio.Types.PhoneNumber("username2"),
    sipAuthUsername: "xxx",
    sipAuthPassword: "xxx",
    url: new Uri("https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/<xxx>") // TwiML to connect to the video room
);
```

...which fails with: Error - 32009 - Dialing SIP Endpoint failure - User not registered

Not sure where to go from here - given the advice on the Twilio debugger indicates that it's the lack of a SIP client registered to the endpoint that's a problem... But there shouldn't be a SIP client involved? I'm just hoping to use the Twilio as a SIP endpoint in the same way as a phone number would be used - ie: to accept incoming calls and execute TwiML instructions.

Hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Registered SIP end-points must use the US1 region, so you need to modify the URL to be sip:xxx.sip.us1.twilio.com.

You can find more details on how to register a SIP end-point directly to Twilio [HERE](https://www.twilio.com/blog/registering-sip-phone-twilio-inbound-outbound). The Voice URL for your SIP Domain would return TwiML which would add the SIP end-point as a voice participant using the [Connect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/connect) Verb (Connect a Call to a Room Code Example).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I've changed to using the US1 region, with no luck. I've also updated the question (a typo fix and clarification) - the article you've linked to isn't the direction I'm trying to go - as I stated, I'm not looking to register a SIP phone of any sort - I'm hoping for Twilio to handle the incoming call entirely.

Comment: Your code above is calling a Twilio SIP Domain/End-point. If you are calling a non-registered SIP end-point outside of Twilio, use a SIP URI which is a non-Twilio SIP URI, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/sip-making-calls.

Comment: To clarify - I'm not looking to use any SIP infrastructure outside of Twilio at all.

As explained in my original post - I'm trying to use Twilio's SIP calling features to bridge between a conference call and a Programmable Video call.

Comment: There exists a SIP Endpoint (xxx.sip.twilio.com)  < Using this FQDN and the REST API, it must be a registered SIP end-point.

Comment: (in case it helps further clarify, I've corrected that line to read "Domain" rather than "Endpoint") - is it not possible to initiate a SIP call from the REST API that triggers the TwiML response bound to the SIP Domain rather than connecting to an actual end-point?

Comment: Correct, you would need to initiate the request from a SIP User Agent outside Twilio toward your SIP Domain, this will cause the SIP Domain Voice URL TwiML request as you expect. 

If you use the REST API toward a Twilio SIP Domain, Twilio assumes you are trying to communicate to a registered SIP end-point.

Comment: OK - thanks for clarifying. That's a shame - means the use case I'm looking for won't work in an ideal manner. I don't suppose you can think of another way of initiating a call between a Conference and a Programmable Video room? I believe it can work if it's an outgoing call via a Twilio Number, but I'd rather not be initiating a PSTN call from Twilio to Twilio if possible :)

Comment: I believe it would help to step back from the implementation details and explain at a high level what you are trying to achieve? Maybe it can be accomplished by taking a completely different approach. When using the outbound-api to make a call, you are connecting the answering party to whatever TwiML you execute when that party answers. In this case, you have no answering party but TwiML you want to execute to connect a Video Conference with what exactly? I see you say, "I am attempting to join the two" but what two? I only see TwiML returned joining what exactly to the video conference room?

Comment: The end goal is ultimately to have the ability to dial with a standard phone in to a Programmable Video conference, whilst be muted to all other people, including others dialling in via a standard phone.This doesn't appear to be possible using the standard Connect/Room verb (can't mute for other phone callers), so the alternative discussed elsewhere (https://stackoverflow.com/q/58203642/1007439) was to create a Voice Conference Call and connect that conference call to the Video Room.

Comment: Given that there appears to be no direct way of doing this (ie: no way to trigger an conference call to connect to a room, or vice versa), a call that bridges both seemed like the best way to achieve it - hence the solution described in the question above. Does that make sense? (Thanks again for taking the time to help :) )

Comment: Phils approach has the voice only participant dial into a Twilio Phone number (Phone Call) which returns TwiML that joins the participant to a conference muted, using the Conference noun with muted="true". He suggested enabling the conference statusCallbackEvent on that conference, as a trigger (on join event), to then initiate an outbound call to the voice conference using a Dial Verb with Conference Noun, once answered by the conference, execute TwiML which returns a Connect Verb and Room Noun to join the Video Conference. You need to make sure only the first join triggers this connection.

Comment: You can use  a combination of TwiML Bins (static TwiML) for the inbound voice conference call and Twilio Functions (Node.js/JavaScript) to consume the statusCallbackEvent and generate a REST API call to connect the voice conference and once answered, use another TwiML Bin to return the static TwiML to join the Video Conference (this is the URL in the REST API Calls Resource) to the Voice Conference.

Comment: You would need to make sure the REST API call is only fired one, since you only want to join the conferences together once (so somehow there needs to be some state or an API call to make sure there is only 1 participant in the conference - that's sort of how I see it). Have you worked with Twilio Functions before?

Comment: Haven't worked with them, but we're currently using our own REST service to handle the events, and are able to track the events perfectly fine. This is indeed the solution I've been building. As stated above, the only real issue we've had is the actual act of bridging the two conferences - ie: option 1: using a PSTN connection works, but is not ideal (cost, complexity, etc), option 2: using a SIP line fails with the errors listed above.